# SharePoint 2007 and its underlying operating systems

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

We have a MOSS 2007 Standard farm, running on 2 Web Front End (WFE) and 1 Indexing server all running on 64 bit Windows Server 2003 servers.

We need to upgrade our servers to Windows Server 2008, and wanted to know if you can run 1 WFE on Windows 2008 and 1 WFE on Windows 2003, while we are in the process of upgrading our individual servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally was able to get my network team to set me up a VM so that I could test running MOSS 2007 in a mixed OS environment.  I can confirm that for MOSS 2007 you can run different servers with different operating systems.  I have one WFE running 2003 and one running 2008.  There are no compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a lot of experience with MOSS, but haven't actually tried this. However, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work; the MOSS instances should still 'talk' to each other the same way, regardless of the underlying Windows operating system.

I have ran an 64-bit Windows 2003 indexing server and 4 32-bit Windows 2003 WFEs with no issue.

If you have a test environment, I'd recommend trying it there first.

Comment: Thanks.  We have a Development environment that we are going to test this on first.  I was just curious if anyone had any previous experience with this type of situation.

I'll post the results here.